# Korrekte Bezeichnung von Professoren im Text

Tags: person-names, salutation, letter

Ich kenne die Regeln für Professoren für die Anschrift und für die Anrede. Wie verweise ich jedoch korrekterweise im Text auf die Person? Beispielsweise in einem Brief:

> Das wird Ihnen auch [Person] bestätigen.

Für mich steht zur Auswahl:

> Das wird Ihnen auch ...
>
> - Herr Professor
> - Herr Prof.
> - Professor
> - Prof.
> - Prof. Dr.
>
> ... Mustermann bestätigen.

Gibt es hierfür eine Regel (am besten mit Quelle)?

Comment: Hängt wahrscheinlich vom Grad der Vertrautheit mit dem Zuhörer und dem Professor und dessen Verhältnis zum Professor ab. Also wie formell soll es sein? Ich persönlich würde sagen "Das kann Ihnen auch Professor Mustermann bestätigen".

Comment: Im Text soll man Professor auch nicht zu Prof. abkürzen. So interpretiere ich jedenfalls https://www.zaar.uni-muenchen.de/studium/studenteninfo/student_prof/kommunikation/index.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was man hier schreiben sollte, hängt einerseits vom Statusbewusstsein des betreffenden Professors ab, andererseits von der Intention des Sprechers.

Ich kenne Professoren, für die

> Das wird Ihnen auch Herr Mustermann bestätigen.

völlig in Ordnung ist.

Unter Kollegen ist sogar

> Das wird Ihnen auch Mustermann bestätigen.

nicht unüblich.<sup>[1]</sup>

Wenn man sich darüber nicht sicher ist, ob sich Herr Mustermann dadurch mglw. nicht ausreichend ästimiert und daher in seiner Ehre herabgesetzt sieht, sollte man

> Das wird Ihnen auch Herr Professor Mustermann bestätigen.

schreiben, um die Form zu wahren. Hier wird Herr Mustermann angeführt, und es wird ganz ordnungsgemäß sein Professorentitel genannt.

Schreibt man hingegen

> Das wird Ihnen auch Professor Mustermann bestätigen.

so betont dies, dass man Herrn Mustermann als Autorität zitiert. Er ist dann nicht nur jemand, der den fraglichen Umstand bestätigt, und nebenbei auch Professor ist, sondern die beiden Umstände, dass er Professor ist (also diesen akadamischen Titel trägt) und dass er den fraglichen Umstand bestätigt, werden besonders verknüpft. Dies geschieht dadurch, dass *Professor* hier nicht mehr nur als Titel genannt wird, sondern als Funktion, die die gewöhnliche Anrede *Herr* ersetzt. Der Herr Mustermann wird damit also *als Professor* angesprochen (Ganz analog wäre hier *Das wird Ihnen Schornsteinfegermeister Mustermann bestätigen.*) Diese Art der Ansprache des Professor-Seins scheint insbesondere dann angebracht, wenn der fragliche Umstand in die fachliche Expertise von Herrn Mustermann fällt.

> Das wird Ihnen auch Prof. Dr. Mustermann bestätigen.

verschärft diesen Eindruck, weil es noch förmlicher ist, und zwar über das Maß des in der gesprochenen Sprache Üblichen hinaus. Die Verschärfung entsteht in meinen Augen auch durch den Umstand, dass Professoren ohnehin in aller Regel auch Doktoren sind, mit einigen wenigen Ausnahmen, vor Allem in musischen/künstlerischen Fächern und bei Professoren ehrenhalber.

Ebenso

> Das wird Ihnen auch Herr Prof. Dr. Mustermann bestätigen.

Beides klingt sehr gestelzt und betont in meinen Ohren den Status von Herrn Mustermann als Autorität in einem Maße, das übertrieben wirkt. Aber das ist natürlich sehr subjektiv.

[1]: Das gilt auch für Autoritäten, die bereits Klassiker sind, und als solche angesprochen werden. Also etwa *Das wird Ihnen auch Habermas bestätigen.*, wenn es um eine Aussage geht, die aus Habermas' Theorie stammt.

Comment: Muss man bei _Das wird Ihnen auch Professor Mustermann bestätigen._ **Professor** ausschreiben oder kann man auch **Prof.** schreiben?

Comment: Ich denke, man sollte es ausschreiben. Siehe auch den Kommentar von jjack unter der Frage.